# Formik React-Native - How to Show Yup Validation Errors on Each Field in an Array of Objects

Tags: typescript, react-native, formik, yup

So I'm trying to make a list of contacts, here's the code:

Yup Schema:

```
export const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
/**other fields */

contacts: Yup.array().required('Required field').of(
    Yup.object().required('Required!').shape({
        id: Yup.number(),
        name: Yup.string().required('Required field!'),
        phone: Yup.string().required('Required field!'),
        email: Yup.string().email('Type a valid Email!').required('Required field!')
    })
)})
```

Formik Component:

```
const Form = () => {

return (

 <View>  
   <Formik 
    validationSchema={Schema}
    initialValues: {
        /* other values */
        contacts: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: '',
                phone: '',
                email: ''
            }
        ]
    }
>
{({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, setFieldValue, errors, touched, values }) => {


    function addNewContact() {
        setFieldValue('contacts', [
            ...values.contacts,
            { id: values.contacts[values.contacts.length - 1].id + 1, name: '', phone: '', email: '' }
        ])
    }

    return (
        /**A lot of inputs here*/

        {values.contacts.map(({ id, email, name, phone }, index) => (
            <View key={id}>
                <Text>Name *</Text>
                <Input
                    value={name}
                    onChangeText={handleChange(`contacts[${index}].name`)}
                    onBlur={handleBlur(`contacts[${index}].name`)}
                />
                {(errors.contacts ? errors.contacts[index].name : false)
                    && (touched.contacts ? touched.contacts[index].name : false)
                    && <Text>{`${errors.contacts[index].name}`}</Text>}

                /**Repeat the above with phone and email */
            </View>
        ))}
    )
}}

    </Formik>
  </View>
)}

export default Form
```

My problem is when displaying the errors, I can't access them. In the way that is written above, intellisense says that `name` from `errors.contacts[index].name` does not exist on type `string | FormikErrors<IContactProps>`

I've tried to remove the ternary operator condition, but it tells me that contacts is possibly undefined.

When I `console.log(errors.contacts)`, it shows the array I was supose to be able to access with `errors.contacts[index].name`.

Even with that intellisense error, my code runs and works with 1 contact. When I add 2 or more contacts,
the app throws when I text on an Input: `undefined is not an object (evaluating errors.contacts[index].name)`

How can I properly access these errors on an Array of objects? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in other way, not the ideal.

```
{errors.contacts && errors.contacts[index] && Object.values(errors.contacts[index]).map((err, j) => (
     <Text key={j + id}>{err}</Text>
))}
```

I put this right below `View key={id}`. So instead of showing error in each field of contacts, I'm showing all together above the inputs.

If someone knows how to solve the previous issue, I'll be glad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution to this, I'm pretty sure this is a bug: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/2347